# Can you level up offline in Call of Duty 4: Modern Warfare?

Tags: call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare

I don't have Xbox live or even internet, but I would still like to create my own class (as far as I know you have to be on level 4 for that and you have to be online to level up) on COD 4. I also have modern warfare 3 and in there you can level up in the local multiplayer. I was wondering if you can do the same in the first game.

Can you level up without going online?

I don't know if its important but I am playing on an Xbox 360.

Comment: As far as I can remember you have separate online and offline profiles - so if you play LAN games or private matches your progress is tracked separately, then if you go online you won't have any progress.

Comment: I am still not able to level up when offline though

Comment: you still have to play against people offline (in LAN play) - you can't just start a game by yourself and earn points...

Comment: I understand that. I play locally with my brothers but we don't have levels.

Comment: @BlippThePanda i think you answered your own question then, correct? You can post this as an answer and accept it

Answer (score 1):

There are no levels in offline, it is simply 5 classes that you can choose from. The only way you can create your own classes is by playing online.

Sorry to dissapoint.

References: Personal Experience.

Answer (score 1):

Unfortunately, no. There is no offline progress.

[Reference](https://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/939212-call-of-duty-4-modern-warfare/answers/98477-can-i-make-m-own-class-on-splitscreen)

> No. Custom Classes are only available in online multiplayer. Splitscreen and system link must use pre-set classes.

If you have the ability or desire, Call of Duty: Modern Warfare 2 *does* have offline create a class.

[Reference](https://www.gamefaqs.com/xbox360/951944-call-of-duty-modern-warfare-2/answers/129474-create-a-class-splitscreen)

> The offline split screen is an exact copy of the online system, though they are separate so they don't transfer between each other. You can do everything in split screen, that you can do in online play.

Answer (score 0):

Yes indeed, but the issue is the term "level" differs in single player mode and multiplayer mode in cod4. someone might be level 1 on sp while being lvl55 on mp vice versa.
so you can play game levels on solo mode to level up the mode, and you can play online/lan to level up on multiplayer mode.